# How to fix the error when i issue any query in mysql from express | LINUX DEBIAN?

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, express

on LINUX DEBIAN

I have the code below:

[image]

this is a simple query that i want to get, but when i send a post request to the route, i get this message in my terminal

[image]

Comment: My best guess is that you are re-using the same connection object. You probably need to look into making a 'mysql pool'.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, but place the actual code into the post.